# How to list all network sites on one page

Tags: multisite, list

Can I list all the blogs in my network on one page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, small source for an template.

```
<ul class='postlist no-mp'>

<?php 
/**
 * Old version, change on 07/23/2013
 *
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
    WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
    AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
    AND spam = '0' 
    AND deleted = '0' 
    AND archived = '0' 
    order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
); 
 */

// get all blogs
$blogs = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );

if ( 0 < count( $blogs ) ) :
    foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : 
        switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );

        if ( get_theme_mod( 'show_in_home', 'on' ) !== 'on' ) {
            continue;
        }

        $description  = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        $blog_details = get_blog_details( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
        ?>
        <li class="no-mp">

            <h2 class="no-mp blog_title">
                <a href="<?php echo $blog_details->path ?>">
                    <?php echo  $blog_details->blogname; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>

            <div class="blog_description">
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
            query_posts( 'showposts=5' );
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="blog_post">
                        <div class="post_title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_excerpt">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; 
            restore_current_blog();
            ?>
        </li>
<?php endforeach;
endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: this one didnt work. Got an error on the endforeach;

Comment: sorry, i have forgotten an endif, last line; now it works; have tested now.

Comment: Small hint to use it without a db select. Current in my projects I use this snippet: `$blogs = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' ); `. This get a array of data about all blogs inside the MU network. Is easier to maintenance. All data to each blog can get the the follow snipper `get_blog_details( $blog['blog_id'] )`. Maybe this helps as note to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This will print out an unordered list of all public sites in a multisite network:

```
// $bcount = get_blog_count();
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'");
if(!empty($blogs)){
    ?><ul class="menu"><?php
    foreach($blogs as $blog){
        $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);
        if($details != false){
            $addr = $details->siteurl;
            $name = $details->blogname;
            if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))){
                ?>
                <li class="menu-item<?php if($counter == get_current_blog_id()){ echo ' current-menu-item';}?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?></ul><?php
}
```

Comment: ahh, thank you!! is it possible to show these alphabeticly?

Comment: Instead of echoing them out, store them in an array using the blogs name as the key, do an array sort, then echo out each item in the array

Comment: Why do you need first line (`$bcount = get_blog_count();`)? This variable is not used anywhere.

Comment: Indeed it isn't, perhaps that line should be removed

Comment: Hi! Tom J, Hi! Your code works well for me. But, I have a question. I want to exclude certain site from appearing from this list. How can it be done? Thank you!

Comment: You'd check for that site in the loop and skip if it's the site you want to exclude. Never ask the database to do the excluding part, it's always faster/safer to do it in PHP with an `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution written basing on *Tom J Nowell* idea and answer. It prints out sorted list of all sites in Wordpress Multisite installation, as simple line (separated with pipe).

To get this solution running, edit your currently selected theme and select `shortcodes.php` from right sidebar. Near the end of this file, before first occurence of `add_shortcode` call add following function:

```
function theme_list_all_network_sites()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $result = '';
    $sites = array();
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'"));

    if(!empty($blogs))
    {
        foreach($blogs as $blog)
        {
            $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);

            if($details != false)
            {
                $url = $details->siteurl;
                $name = $details->blogname;

                if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1) && ($show_main != 1)))
                {
                    $sites[$name] = $url;
                }
            }
        }

        ksort($sites);

        $count = count($sites);
        $current = 1;

        foreach($sites as $name=>$url)
        {
            $result.= '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a>';
            $result.= ($current == $count) ? "\n" : ' | ';

            ++$current;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Then scroll down to the end of file and after last occurence of `add_shortcode` add:

```
add_shortcode('network_list', 'theme_list_all_network_sites');
```

Click `Update File` to save your changes.

Now, whenever anyone use `[network_list]` shortcode to in post, page or theme element, a list of network sites will be printed in place of that shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress 4.6.0, I offer you a more modern way to "list" (or more) :

```
<?php $sites_q = new \WP_Site_Query( [
    'site__not_in' => get_main_site_for_network(),
] );
$sites_for_network = $sites_q->get_sites();
if ( ! empty( $sites_for_network ) ) {
    $original_site_id = get_current_blog_id();
    foreach ( $sites_for_network as $site ) {
         /** @var $site \WP_Site */
         switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
         // Do stuff with the site
    }
    switch_to_blog( $original_site_id );
}
```