# List recent 25 blogs across the network

Tags: multisite, sql

I need to list recent 25 blogs in the network with their title. How to edit this code ?

```
$bcount = get_blog_count();

  global $wpdb;
  $blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'"));
   if(!empty($blogs)){
?><ul class="menu"><?php
foreach($blogs as $blog){
    $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);
    if($details != false){
        $addr = $details->siteurl;
        $name = $details->blogname;
        if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))){
            ?>
            <li class="menu-item<?php if($counter == get_current_blog_id()){ echo ' current-menu-item';}?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?></ul><?php
}
```

Comment: If you're _stealing_ someone else code, at least be so kind to give proper credit. You're not an author of the code in your question. It comes from [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41792/17323) to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41790/how-to-list-all-network-sites-on-one-page).

Answer (score 3):

You just have to modify your query to get only first 25 matches `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1' limit 25`.

The result is already order by `id` what is incremented automatically, you don't have anything to bother about there.

Also please note, it is not a good practice to do such queries on every request, you should cache them.