# Show image or notification on specific blog in multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a multisite. I am trying to create a simple plugin that will allow me to select website(blog) from the list of all website in my multisite.

How to show some image or notification(text or html code) on a specific blog based on what I have selected from the list. On each blog I can show different image or notification(text or html code).

I have found many ways how to get the lists of all the blogs in the multisite like [here](http://blogbysid.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/return-a-list-of-sites-on-the-wordpress-multisite-network/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41790/how-to-list-all-network-sites-on-one-page)

My problem is, after I select a specific blog, how to show in the plugin dash only the image or notification(text or html code) that I am to to show to this blog.

Answer (score 0):

check the [get_current_blog_id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) function; that'll return the ID of the current blog.